# EPSON Stylus CX3650 doesn't print

Tags: 20.04, printing, epson, stylus

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 a few weeks ago. I had Debian 8 before and my Epson Stylus CX3650 printed normally (scanner wasn't recognized, though). Now, I can scan but can't print. The printer is recognized, Ubuntu shows that the job is sent to the printer and printed, but the printer doesn't do anything.
Is there something else I can do for this printer to work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this package with gdebi:

https://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/debian/dists/lsb3.2/contrib/binary-amd64/openprinting-gutenprint_5.2.7-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did it but still the same: Ubuntu shows that the job is sent to the printer and printed, but the printer doesn't do anything.